# Using command line rename files based on a list

Tags: vbscript

I'm using it command to rename some files, the point is que When I try usalo through the script does not work, something que does not Occur in batch.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.Run("cmd.exe /C For /f ""usebackq delims="" %%a in (""C:\MY FILES\LIST.txt"") do (If Exist ""%%a"" Ren ""%%a"" ""*.txt"")"), 1, True
```

.
    **List:**

```
"A\a1.ini"
"A\a1_1.ini"
"A\a2.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for /f` loop is not running inside a batch file, but in *command line context*, a direct command inside a `cmd` instance.

`for` replaceable parameters are written as `%a`, and the percent sign needs to be escaped doubling it (`%%a`) *when used inside a batch file*. But as indicated this is not your case.